# Does Read have any limit

Tags: c, sockets, size, limit

i'm trying to implement a client-server application with sockets, the case is that i want to read in the server a message that is large. And the read is doing unexpected things.
This is my read message implementation (I have received the size of the message first)

```
        ssize_t bytesRead=0;
        while (bytesRead < size_msg_){
            ssize_t ret = read(s_conec,msg+bytesRead,SSIZE_MAX);
            if (ret == 0)
                break; //EOF
            bytesRead +=ret;
            int aux = ( (bytesRead * 100)/size_msg_ );
            printf("I have read a %d percent \n", aux); 
}
```

Now, if i try to see what the server is reading with strace i get this:

```
read(7, "En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuy"..., 2147483647) = 873056
read(7, " sino de amores -respondi\303\263 don "..., 2147483647) = 523864
read(7, "o, por parecerme que, en la ley "..., 2147483647) = 458381
read(7, " con \303\251l se defend\303\255a de la nube"..., 2147483647) = 458381
read(7, " que all\303\241 quedan y aqu\303\255 van le"..., 2147483647) = 458381
read(7, " otros semejantes pasaron la noc"..., 2147483647) = 458381
read(7, "rlas. Acudi\303\263 Sancho a su asno p"..., 2147483647) = 458381
read(7, " Quijote dec\303\255a, y, celoso de qu"..., 2147483647) = 2160939
```

And so on, with no pattern. What i want to know is if there is any limit assiciated with the read function that i could change because this implementaion takes to long to read the full message

Comment: `if(ret == 0)` should be `if(ret == EOF)`   (where  `EOF == -1`).  from [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read)

Comment: What does _recibed_ mean?

Comment: received, sorry

Comment: [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) is more on `read`, including good detail on its limits.  In general, _limits_ are always a reality, but I doubt `read` is bumping into them in terms of its keeping up.  Tweek the arguments and how you evaluate the return value in your implementation  (test for `EOF` not `0`

Comment: what do you mean by Tweek the arguments ?

Comment: Sorry, Poorly stated, I should have said adjust the way you are calling it, not only the arguments and return ( `ssize_t ret = read(s_conec,msg+bytesRead,SSIZE_MAX);
            if (ret == 0)` ) but also the environment in which you are calling it.   One obvious thing to look at for example `msg+bytesRead` could be problematic, it is supposed to be a `buffer`, with `size == sizeof(buffer)`  For more specific help, provide a [mcve], this will result in a better set of ideas from others who see your problem.

Comment: It's the way reading sockets works.   It's a byte stream, and you read what is ready to be read.  Any particular reason you use `read` over `recv`?

Comment: I fixed it by using recv with MSG_WAITALL and it work. Thank you guys